# Chainlink fulfillOracleRequest with Large bytes data

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

In order to receive a full url trough a chainlink Oracle I would like to pass bytes to my fulfillment method.

`fulfillOracleRequest` are sent by the node but my Oracle contract rejects them. [I suspect it can only accept byte32 data](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.6/Oracle.sol#L125). According to [Chainlink's documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/) it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Operator.sol from 0.7 instead of Oracle.sol